# Facebook: field expansion in batch requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request, facebook-field-expansion

Is it possible to make a batch request with one (or more) of the batched requests using field expansion?

For instance, say I'd like information about me, my listen data. These are the three batch requests I wrap up:

```
{'method': 'GET', 'relative_url': 'me'}
{'method': 'GET', 'relative_url': 'me/music.listens'}
{'method': 'GET', 'relative_url': 'me/friends?fields=name,first_name,last_name,music.listens.limit(1)'}
```

But when I make the batch request, the first two responses come back with the data I expect and the third response comes back with data in this format (not the data I requested):

```
{'access_token': '<access token here>'}
```

I read all about batch requests here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

and about field expansions here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even combine this into one query:

```
/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,music.listens,friends.fields(name,first_name,last_name,music.listens.limit(1))
```

I noticed that you have a surplus "u" in your request definition

{'method': 'GET', 'relative_url': **u**'me'}

maybe you should fix this. Anyway, as I said, you dont need the Batch API to combine the requests.

Comment: Sorry, I was pasting in the python dicts I was passing, so those surplus "u"s were just referring to unicode strings. I tried what you suggested and it worked perfectly - thanks for the tip!